# Is $(ab+1)^{a^n}-1$ always divisible by $a^{n+1}b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, divisibility, binomial-theorem

Let $a,b,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, and consider the expression $(ab+1)^{a^n}-1$. No matter which positive integers I try, I always get that $(ab+1)^{a^n}-1$ is divisible by $a^{n+1}b$. Can this be true in general?

Let's try to find out! By the binomial theorem, $$(ab+1)^{a^n}=\sum_{k=0}^{a^n}\binom{a^n}{k}(ab)^{k}.$$

It seems like all terms but the first (which equals $1$) should be divisible by $a^{n+1}b$, and then the claim would follow. However, it this intuition actually correct?

Note: For a prime $p$, we know that [$\binom{p}{r}$ is divisible by $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149707/divisibility-of-binomial-coefficients-by-primes). But $a^n$ is not necessarily prime here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prove by induction on $n$, the base case $n = 0$ is trivial. Now suppose $a^n b \mid (ab + 1)^{a^{n - 1}} - 1$. Because$$
(ab + 1)^{a^n} - 1 = ((ab + 1)^{a^{n - 1}} - 1) \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{a - 1} ((ab + 1)^{a^{n - 1}})^k \right),
$$
and$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{a - 1} ((ab + 1)^{a^{n - 1}})^k \equiv \sum_{k = 0}^{a - 1} 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{a} \Longrightarrow \left. a \,\middle|\, \sum_{k = 0}^{a - 1} ((ab + 1)^{a^{n - 1}})^k \right.,
$$
then$$
\frac{(ab + 1)^{a^n} - 1}{a^{n + 1} b} = \frac{(ab + 1)^{a^{n - 1}} - 1}{a^n b} · \frac{1}{a} \sum_{k = 0}^{a - 1} ((ab + 1)^{a^{n - 1}})^k \in \mathbb{Z},
$$
i.e.$$
\left. a^{n + 1} b \,\middle|\, (ab + 1)^{a^n} - 1 \right..
$$
End of induction.

Comment: Never mind, I see where I missed.  Just deleted my comments.   Confused summing 1's with summing consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Mind that

$$
(1+x)^n = 1+n x+ \frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\cdots+x^n
$$

and

$$
(1+x)^n - 1 = n x+ \frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\cdots+x^n
$$

or

$$ 
(1+ab)^{a^n} - 1 = a^{n+1}b P(a,b)
$$

hence

$$
(1+ab)^{a^n} - 1 \equiv 0 \mod a^{n+1}b
$$

Comment: Why does the third equality follow? This step is what I'm trying to prove!

Comment: It is sufficient that $a > 1$ in which case $a ^ n > n + 1$ Mind that the last expansion term is $(ab)^{a^n}$

Comment: How do you prove that $\binom{a^n}{k}$ is divisible by $a^{n+1-k}$? This is essentially what the third equality says.