# Algebraic expansion of $1 + (1 + x) + ... + (1 + x)^{p-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, summation

I was proving that $p(x) = 1 + x + \text{ ... }  + x^{p-1}$, where $p$ is a prime number, is irreducible over the rationals, by using the translation $1 + (1 + x) + \text{ ... } + (1 + x)^{p-1}$. I managed to do it, but I would like to get a closed expression for this as a polynomial.

So far, I have:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k = 0}^{p-1}{(1+x)^k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1}{(\sum_{i = 0}^k{\binom{k}{i}x^i)}} 
\end{equation}

By inspection, it looks like the final result will be:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k = 0}^{p-1}{(1+x)^k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1}{(\sum_{i=k}^{p-1}{\binom{i}{k}}} )x^k 
\end{equation}

I.E.

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{\binom{i}{0}} + \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}{\binom{i}{1}} x + \text{ ... } + \sum_{i=p-1}^{p-1}{\binom{i}{p-1}}x^{p-1} 
\end{equation}

First of all, is this correct? If not, what would be the correct expression and why? And if it is correct, how can I get from the first equation to the second?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm just wondering, how did you prove the irreducibility of the series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that I have not misinterpreted your query:

A case can be made that the following hint-answer is defective, because it avoids examining your work.  Through no fault of your own, you went down a natural **but bad** path.

I actually don't know how to prove that any polynomial is irreducible, but I can give you a hint about how to **very easily** find a closed form expression for the requested polynomial.

Hint-1:
Given the geometric series, 
$f(t) = 1 + t + t^2 + \cdots + t^n$, what is the result of 
$f(t) \times (1-t)$?

Hint-2:
What happens if you set $t = (x+1)$?

Comment: Thank you so much, @user2661923! I hadn't even thought of that!

Answer (score 1):

If $p\in\Bbb P$ then for $0\le k\le p-1$ the $x^k$ coefficient in $\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}(1+x)^j$ is $\sum_{j=k}^{p-1}\binom{j}{k}=\binom{p}{k+1}$ by the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity). This is presumably how you proved irreducibility by [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion), since [the non-leading coefficients will be multiples of $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149707/divisibility-of-binomial-coefficients-by-primes). This implies the closed form$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\binom{p}{k+1}x^k=\frac1x\sum_{\ell=1}^p\binom{p}{\ell}x^\ell=\frac{(1+x)^p-1}{x},$$but that's more easily obtained by @user2661923's strategy. Both approaches make obvious that this closed form is true even for composite $p$.

Comment: Thank you for a direct proof, @J.G.! The links were very helpful!